# Eclipse show no error in files but in folder

Tags: android, eclipse

I got this error when code my Android app:

[image]

I do nothing to this strings.xml file.

Can anyone fix this error?

I do refresh and clean but nothing change.

Thanks.

Comment: Did you try cleaning the project?

Comment: Yes, i did clean, refresh, close and reopen, restart eclipse but nothing happen .

Comment: Try to remove the project from your workspace. And, again import that. In your `Strings.xml` what it contains from folder `values-vi`

Comment: @SpK : I know this is not a good way to solve this problem but I commit all my code then delete project and import again, it works. Please answer then I will mark your answer. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per your [Comment.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10765378/eclipse-show-no-error-in-files-but-in-folder#comment13994856_10765378) Here i post my answer. For this problem. Try below steps -

- First just remove the project from your workspace.
- And, after just import that project again into your work-space.

Sometimes, it happened for me. I tried to do this way. It works.

Hope this helps you.

Answer (score 1):

Most Often this happens to me too.
Try to remove project from workspace and re-import it.

Hope it will work :)

Answer (score 0):

It seems you have used localization is your app.
There are different possibilities for the error to occur:

1)You have not localized all of the strings.
2)Other problems are persisting and you are not ignoring them.

Solution:

Right Click on your project----> Java Compiler-----> Errors/Warning---> Remove all errors

let me know if this works.

Comment: There is no "Remove all errors" (Eclipse Juno) and for me the problem does not seem to be localization.

Answer (score 0):

What version of the SDK are you compiling against? According to [this](http://colincooper.net/blog/2011/02/17/android-supported-language-and-locales/) list, you need at least Android 2.3 for Vietnamese localisation.